# Maybe application of Helly theorem

Tags: discrete-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact subset of $R^n$. Prove that if any $≤ n + 1$ points of $X$ can be covered by a unit ball not containing the origin then the whole $X$ can be covered by a unit ball not containing the origin.

Note: If we remove the condition that unit ball not containing the origin, then the solution is just a simple use of Helly theorem.

Comment: How do you prove the claim in the "Note"?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/ConvexSets/HellysTheoremApplications.shtml @Rigel

Comment: Note that if a set of points can be covered by _any_ ball not containing the origin, they can be covered by a unit ball not containing the origin.